# How to check if any words present in a string is available in an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, contain, sentence

i just want to ask if user input sentence is present in the array. like for example "Vince borrow book" then i just want to check if "Vince" "Borrow" and "Book" are present in arrays. im noob

```
string sentence = tbSentence.Text;
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words) 
{
    if(subjectarray.Any(word.Contains) && verbarray.Any(word.Contains))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sentence Valid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Right - a question in the tile, with a (poorly formatted) code fragment in the question body does not make a question that can be answered.  What exactly is it that you are trying to do?  Please add some context around your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check that ALL words are in subjectarray AND verbarray (sure is "AND" and not "OR"?), so:

```
bool valid = words.All(w=>subjectarray.Contains(w) && verbarray.Contains(w));
```